# One-step ahead forecast of a AR(1) process (GARCH context)

Tags: garch, forecasting, matlab, arima, mean

I am using a **Matlab** toolbox for obtaining **one-step ahead forecasts** of the **conditional mean** from the **ARMA(1,0)-GARCH(1,1)** process and I have encountered a piece of code that contains, in my opinion, a mistake. The full code of the forecasting function is available for viewing at: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32882-armax-garch-k-toolbox--estimation--forecasting--simulation-and-value-at-risk-applications-/content/garchfor.m

The fragment that I was referring to is:

```
% Forecasting the Mean
MF = parameters(1:1+z)'*[1; data(end-(1:ar)); resids(end-(0:ma-1))]; % 1-period ahead forecast
 for i = 2:max_forecast
     MF(i,1) = sum([parameters(1); ones(1,ar)*parameters(2:2+ar)*MF(i-1,1); ones(1,ma)*parameters(3+ar:2+ar+ma)*resids(end-(0:ma-1-i))]);
 end
 clear i
```

From this code it seems that when I am considering **ARMA(1,0)** the function takes the one before last observation for the forecast. In other words, when the data spans time points $1,...,t$ and I want to obtain a forecast for period $t+1$ I multiply the AR(1) coefficient by the $t-1$ observation.In my opinion, for time $t+1$ AR(1) forecast I should be taking the last observation ($t$) from the data-set and multiply it by the AR(1) coefficient.

Could you please confirm my suspicions about this piece of code?

Comment: Probably do the microsurgery on your own by looking at this http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9351/algorithm-to-fit-ar1-garch1-1-model-of-log-returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct regarding your question (and only for an AR(1) ), you made a mistake because the last observation of the data set is $t-1$ and not $t$ since you are forecasting the point at time $t$.

In the code : `MF(i,1)` is the current point forecast ($t$) and lag one observation ( `MF(i-1,1)`  which is  $t-1$  ) is correctly related to the AR part.

However it seems to me that there is an error in the following part :

```
ones(1,ar)*parameters(2:2+ar)*MF(i-1,1)
```

It is only correct if you are estimating an AR(1) , for a higher order the `MF(i-1,1)` part is wrong because you apply different coefficients to the same  observation ( ex : $ \alpha_{1} y_{t-1} + \alpha_{2} y_{t-1} $ instead of  $\alpha_{1} y_{t-1} + \alpha_{2} y_{t-2} $ ). I would recommend you to use more reliable codes such as functions you can find in the [MFE Toolbox](https://www.kevinsheppard.com/MFE_Toolbox).

Comment: I will investigate the MFE Toolbox, I remember that I couldn't find everything I needed there, but I will give it another look. But back to your answer, I am still not sure I understand correctly. Let's say I have an estimation sample of a 100 observations and an evaluation sample of 1 observation. So when I estimate the ARMA(1,0)-GARCH(1,1) model on the estimation sample and want to make this one one-step ahead forecast of the conditional mean ( for this time = 101) i multiply the AR(1) coefficient by observation number 99 or 100?

Comment: I was investigating this matter with the `fGarch` package and it seems that 100 would be he answer in this case, as such manual calculations yield the same result as the prediction done using the built-in function.

Comment: to forecast observation 101 you multiply the ar(1) by observation 100, if you fit a AR(2) you multiply ar(1) by obs (100) and ar(2) by obs(99)

Comment: That is what I have though, so only in the case of the one-step ahead out-of-sample AR(1) forecasting `MF = parameters(1:1+z)'*[1; data(end); resids(end-(0:ma-1))];` this modification of the code yields the expected result, as leaving `data(end-(1:ar))` would result in taking the one before last observation of the estimation sample. Thank you for your help @Malick